# Core-geth/Go-Ethereum: Why ReorgNeeded called before check if canonical block, in WriteBlockAndSetHead in blockchain.go?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic

When running as a block producer, a `chainHeadEvent` is sent to worker.go after producing a block, and this is done via `WriteBlockAndSetHead` that is called from `resultLoop` after receiving a new sealed block (also in Go-Ethereum until a week ago with [commit d8e0807da22eb922539d15b0d5d01ccdd58b1267](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/d8e0807da22eb922539d15b0d5d01ccdd58b1267)). I noticed that `WriteBlockAndSetHead` uses `ReorgNeeded` in what to me seems a bit unconventional. It uses it simply to check if the block total difficulty is higher, regardless of if it is on the canonical chain (if its parent block is the current block. ) It then, after that, does a check about if the block is canonical or not. Is there a reason why it is done in that order, that than the other way around, first checking if the block is on the canonical chain, and if not, checking `ReorgNeeded`?

```
currentBlock := bc.CurrentBlock()
reorg, err := bc.forker.ReorgNeeded(currentBlock, block.Header())
if err != nil {
    return NonStatTy, err
}
if reorg {
    // Reorganise the chain if the parent is not the head block
    if block.ParentHash() != currentBlock.Hash() {
        if err := bc.reorg(currentBlock, block); err != nil {
            return NonStatTy, err
        }
    }
    status = CanonStatTy
} else {
    status = SideStatTy
}
```

**Edit:** Probably because it can. It would work either way, but since a canonical new block is assumed to have higher difficulty anyway, it would waste computation to run it for the blocks that do not pass `ReorgNeeded`.